# Markov Chains: Prove that if $i$ is transient state, then $\pi_i = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

#### Setup

Let $S$ be a countable set and $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N_0}}$ a Markov chain with state space $S$ and transistion matrix $P=\{p_{ij}\}_{i,j \in S}$.

Let furthermore $T_i = \inf\{n \in \mathbb{N} \colon X_n = i\}$. A state $i$ is defined to be *recurrent* if $P(T_i < \infty \mid X_0 = i) = 1 $ and *transient* if $P(T_i < \infty \mid X_0 = i) < 1 $.

A stationary distribution (for $P$) is a vector $\pi = (\pi_i)_{i \in S}$ with $\sum_{i \in S} \pi_i = 1$ satisfying that $\pi = \pi P$.

#### Claim

Assume $\pi = (\pi_i)_{i \in S}$ is a stationary distribution. Prove that if $i$ is transient state, then $\pi_i = 0$.

#### Thoughts

I know that a transient state is only visited finitely many times P-almost surely. Maybe one can prove the claim using this? If we write $P^n = \{p_{ij}^n\}_{i,j \in S}$ then another property of a transient state $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_{ii}^n < \infty$. But I can't quite make it work using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible proof approach.

You say that you already know a transient state $i$ is almost surely visited only finitely many times. Can you show the stronger statement that the *expectation* of the number of visits to $i$ is finite?

Then, denoting the number of visits to $i$ as $N(i) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 1(X_k=i)$,
$$\mathbb{E}[N(i)] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}[1(X_k=i)] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X_k=i) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \pi_i$$
which can only be finite if $\pi_i=0$.

Comment: Why is $P(X_k=i)=\pi_i$? Also is is really true that the expected number of visits would be 0 as well then?

Comment: @Jacobiman because the Markov chain is stationary (per assumption), so every $X_k$ is distributed according to $\pi$

Comment: @Jacobiman and note that the claim basically says that stationary Markov chains almost surely only visit recurrent states, so yes the expected number of visits to transient states should be zero